# HTML5, CSS background-image display problem in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have scoured the stack-overflow quite a bit, and all solutions relevant to this aren't fixing my problem.

So I've been trying to load a background-image onto the figure element.  This works in firefox, chrome, opera, and safari...but of course IE9/8/7 is messing with my head.

```
<figure id="mainlogo">
</figure>
```

with the styles of

```
figure#mainlogo {
  background: url(../images/logocrop.png) no-repeat center;
}
```

I have tried using a div instead of a figure, setting it as display block, getting rid of the id, and almost everything I can find on the net.  Additionally, I've tried separating it out into the separated css styles of background-color, background-image, etc.

I didn't post the rest of the code because this doesn't work even when I separate it out into a separate html file with an inline style it still doesn't show up

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>    
  <figure style="background: url(../images/logocrop.png) no-repeat center; height:40em; width:55em;"></figure>
</body>
</html>
```

I've also tried the other doctypes just to make sure it wasn't that either.  When I set a background color ahead of it, it the color will show.  Anyhow, i have a feeling that this is going to wind up being something fairly obvious and/or easy...Thanks in advance and sorry for the pestering if it's been figured out.

Comment: did you force IE to recognize the figure element by creating one with document.createElement("figure") first?

Comment: Thanks for the response scrappedcola!  But, even when I switch out figure with div it doesn't display

Comment: silly question but when you changed figure to a div did you change the css to target a div?

Answer (score 1):

You could use HTML5 Shiv in order to make IE<9 recognize new elements.

Just add this to your `HEAD`.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script> 
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Yeco.  I tried adding that to the head and it still did nothing :\

Comment: do you have display:block for the figure?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote like that and it worked on IE 9 without any problems (I changed image name for me):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
figure#mainlogo {background: url(../images/header.png) no-repeat center; height:200px; width:1000px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>    
<figure id="mainlogo"></figure>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response.  I tried that as well, and still nothing in mine.  I'm beginning to wonder if it's my computer...

Comment: Does your "Windows Updates" on? Sometimes Microsoft is publishing new updates about IE9 fixes.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer can't style a figure element (it's not supported in most versions).  I'm not sure about the newest version of IE though, it may work on there.

Comment: Hey Hexxagonal.  Thanks for the help.  I switched out the figure with a div element (retargeted the css and all) and I still get nothing on IE9

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten it to work but it seems the only way IE will recognize the figure is to first create the element using document.createElement("figure") and also REMOVE the id. It will style with css just targeting the figure but it freaks out if there is an id present. An example of what I did is here:http://jsfiddle.net/pdq7u/5/ and documentation is here:http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-shiv/.

```
<script>document.createElement("figure");</script>
<style>

figure{
       background:pink url(http://ejohn.org/files/jeresig-wordpress-sm.jpg) no-repeat center; 
    height:200px; 
    width:1000px;
    border:1px solid red;
    display:block;
    }
</style>
<figure>&nbsp;</figure>
```

Note you also need to have it display block so IE doesn't treat it as an inline element.